# Prolog formula parser

Tags: prolog

I have to write a predicate parse(FIn, FOut) that takes a logical formula containing prolog operands "+", "," and ";" as parameter FIn and a logical formula containing "not", "and" and "or" instead of the prolog operands as parameter FOut. The predicate has to return true if FIn and FOut are equivalent.

For example parse(+(a, b), not(and(a, b))) => true

To check if the formulas are negated i can write

```
parse(FIn, FOut) :- isNeg(FIn, FOut).
isNeg(\+(F1), not(F2)).
```

But now i don't know how to check for "," and "and" and ";" and "or".
If anyone has some hints this would be great.

Comment: Something like, `parse(','(A, B), and(Ap, Bp)) :- parse(A, Ap), parse(B, Bp).` Or simply, `parse((A, B), and(Ap, Bp)) :-...`, etc.

Comment: What exactly is this checking? What does parse(A, Ap) mean?

Comment: What I'm showing is how you parse recursively, which is needed to parse an expression like, `+ (a,b)`, or even more complex, `+ (a, (b ; c))` (which I assume you need to handle, or no?). `parse(A, Ap)` means the expression represented by `A` will be further parsed as `Ap`. At some point, you need a base case, which could be something like, `parse(A, A) :- atom(A).` which says that an atom will parse as itself (there's no further parsing to do). So `parse(a, A)` would result in `A = a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the predicate for translating `,` (`;` is similar)

```
% translates (a, b, c, ...) to and(a, and(b, and(c, ...)))
parse(A, A) :- atom(A).

parse((A, B), and(Ao, Bo)) :-
    parse(A, Ao),
    parse(B, Bo).

% translates (a, b, c, ...) to and(a, b, c, ...)
parse1(A, A) :- atom(A).

parse1((A, B), O) :-
    parse1(A, Ao),
    parse1(B, Bo),
    Bo =.. [and | R],
    O =.. [and, Ao | R], !.

parse1((A, B), O) :-
    parse1(A, Ao),
    parse1(B, Bo),
    O =.. [and, Ao, Bo].
```

Prolog is [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity), this allow this kind of predicate to be written nicely.